# Performance issue with PL/SQL when using utl_tcp

Tags: oracle, plsql, tcp

I have written some PL/SQL that connects to a service on prem and gets a very small amount of string data back.  The routine works, but it is incredibly slow, taking roughly 9 seconds to return the data.  I have re-created the process in C# and it gets the results back in under a second, so I assume it is something I am doing wrong in my PL/SQL.  I need to resolve the PL/SQL speed issue as I have to make the call from a very old Oracle Forms application.  Here is the PL/SQL:

```
declare
    c  utl_tcp.connection;
    ret_val varchar2(100);
    reading varchar2(100);
    cmd varchar2(100) := 'COMMAND(STUFF,SERVICE,EXPECTS)';
    cmd2 varchar2(100);
begin
    c := utl_tcp.open_connection(remote_host => 'SERVICE.I.P.ADDRESS'
                               ,remote_port =>  9995
                               ,charset     => 'US7ASCII'
                               ,tx_timeout  => 4
                               );  -- Open connection
                               
    --This is a two step process.  First, issue this command which brings back a sequence number
    ret_val := utl_tcp.write_line(c, cmd);  -- Send command to service
    ret_val := utl_tcp.write_line(c);  -- Don't know why this is necessary, it was in the example I followed
  
    dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_text(c, 100));  -- Read the response from the server
  
    sys.dbms_session.sleep(1); -- This is important as sometimes it doesn't work if it's not slowed down!
  
    --This is the second step which issues another command, using the sequence number retrieved above
    cmd2 := 'POLL(' || ret_val || ')';
        
    reading := utl_tcp.write_line(c, cmd2);  -- Send command to service
    reading := utl_tcp.write_line(c);  --Don't know why this is necessary, it was in the example I followed 
      
    dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_text(c, 100));  -- Read the response from the server    
    utl_tcp.close_connection(c);  --Close the connection
end;
```

I appreciate performance problems are hard to track down when you don't have access to the systems, but any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a first step, have you tried adding some statements to output the `systimestamp` after each call to see where the 9 seconds is going?  If C# runs in under a second, it seems odd that you're adding a `dbms_lock.sleep` call that tries to add a second to your runtime (and the actual sleep may be longer than you asked for).

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave - I took out all of my debug outputs for readability :)  I had to put the sleep in because (and this was from the target system's authors) the second read won't always be available instantly (yes, I know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's this line:

```
dbms_output.put_line(utl_tcp.get_text(c, 100));
```

Are you actually reading 100 characters in your response? If not, it will read the available buffer, wait for the rest of the 100 characters to arrive (but they won't), then timeout.

You've set `tx_timeout` to 4 s. The fact that you have 2 calls to `get_text`, a 1 s `sleep`, and your procedure is taking 9 s suggests to me that's what's going on.

Comment: You have hit the nail on the head.  If I read fewer characters, it comes back very quickly.  In my C# version I am actually reading the byte length of the response and using that as a parameter for how many characters to read.  However, I can't find how to do the same thing (read just the length of the response) in PL/SQL.